# Multiple thunderbird Icons in System Tray(Windows 7) & TaskBar

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird, window

Is this some new "feature" for thunderbird 8? When I start thunderbird it starts by opening thunderbird. Once it is loading thunderbird it loads another 6 thunderbirds.

The windows are called

```
Mozilla Thunderbird 
Inbox - myEmail@gmail.com - Mozilla Thuderbird
Inbox - AotherEmail@gmail.com - Mozilla Thuderbird
Inbox - AotherEmail2@gmail.com - Mozilla Thuderbird
Inbox - AotherEmail2@gmail.com - Mozilla Thuderbird  (yes it repeats the same one a few times)
Inbox - AotherEmail2@gmail.com - Mozilla Thuderbird
```

I have 7 email accounts but for whatever reason it only made 3 windows. What happened to the one window? When I minimize to tray I got 4 of thunderbird icons.

When closing one of them all of the close.

My other windows 7(32 bit not 64 bit) only have one instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Disable "MinimizeToTray Plus" in "Tools -> Add-Ons"
2. Exit Thunderbird (Make sure the process is not running)
3. Start Thunderbird. Thunderbird should be running without the MinimizeToTray Plus add-on.
4. Close one of the MinimizeToTray Plus windows.
5. Re-enable the "MinimizeToTray Plus" add-on
6. Exit and restart Thunderbird.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Run_multiple_copies_of_Thunderbird_at_the_same_time

Comment: I think this may have worked. I will accept this answer in a few days. I want to give it a couple days(and do restarts and shutdowns) to make sure it does not come back.

Comment: hmmm it starting to come back again(it loads 2 up now). Is there a way to permanently stop multiple copes of thunderbird to run?

Comment: Works also in Linux

Comment: I don't know why minimizing to tray is such a big deal, just make it a standard feature Mozilla. We've been down this road so many times now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a new feature, integrating into the Windows 7 Taskbar *better*. It looks like each window will show you a mailbox.

Looking at the [release notes for 6.0](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/6.0/releasenotes/) it shows that they included support for Windows 7 Jumplists.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder why then it does not do all my email account if that is the account. It is missing 3 of them. Any way to merge back all into one?

Comment: I also want to add that my other computers(that have the latest version of thunderbird and have windows 7) do not do this.